# Capturing Mouse Messages - Message.XPos or Message.Pos.x?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have come across this a few times whilst writing custom controls but having come across it again today I felt the need to ask.

Basically when capturing for example:

```
procedure WMLMouseDown(var Message: TWMLButtonDown); message WM_LBUTTONDOWN;
procedure WMMouseMove(var Message: TWMMouseMove); message WM_MOUSEMOVE;
```

To read the X and Y mouse coordinates from the procedure  we have access to either `Message.XPos` or `Message.Pos.x` both of which are declared as `smallint`.

Is there any reason to choose one over the other or do they basically just serve the same purpose and therefore it comes down to choice as to which to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Message.XPos` and `Message.Pos.x` are here completely interchangeable, in usage and in meaning, because they are the same.

All these `Message` parameters are of type `TWMMouse` which is a record type that uses a [variant part](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records) in its declaration:

```
  TWMMouse = record
    Msg: Cardinal;
    MsgFiller: TDWordFiller;
    Keys: Longint;
    KeysFiller: TDWordFiller;
    case Integer of
      0: (
        XPos: Smallint;
        YPos: Smallint;
        XYPosFiller: TDWordFiller;);
      1: (
        Pos: TSmallPoint;
        PosFiller: TDWordFiller;
        Result: LRESULT);
  end;
```

Thus `XPos` and `Pos.X` both read from the same memory. Whether you use one or the other depends on liking.

Answer (score 3):

When writing a custom control, you should be overriding the virtual `MouseDown()` and `MouseMove()` methods, instead of intercepting the underlying window messages directly:

```
procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); dynamic;
procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); dynamic;
procedure MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); dynamic;
```

But to answer your question, yes, you can use either `XPos` or `Pos.x` fields, they both map to the same bits in the message data.

Comment: Ironically I was originally doing this but I was under the impression this was wrong and so I changed it to messages instead. I am interested now in why should I not use messages, is there a strong reason not to?

Comment: Capturing messages is platform-specific, handling virtual methods is portable and cleaner.  The VCL/FMX framework captures the messages internally and translates them for you, so let it do its job.

Comment: Ok you convinced me, I will make those changes right away. Thanks very much for picking up on this.